# How to access network path if any space available in path

Tags: c#, asp.net

my network path

```
//172.12.0.11/karomi snaps/dms/DH2304139/DH2304139_1_2_635023304446654623.jpg
```

now I tried with below but not worked

```
string imagePath = "//172.12.0.11/karomi snaps/dms/DH2304139/DH2304139_1_2_635023304446654623.jpg";

imagePath = "@"+"'" + imagePath +"'"  ;
```

Comment: Should it not be `\\172.12.0.11\karomi snaps\...` etc ?

Comment: so I have to replace "/" to "\" ?

Comment: Also what are you doing with the path afterwards, why the enclosing `'` quotes?

Answer (score 0):

The [UNC format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Uniform_Naming_Convention) for a network file path is:

```
string imagePath = @"\\172.12.0.11\karomi snaps\dms\DH2304139\DH2304139_1_2_635023304446654623.jpg";
```

I've added an `@` to avoid the first two `\` being escaped. The space itself shouldn't cause an issue, assuming the account the app / site is running under has permission to connect to the share. You shouldn't need to wrap this in single quotes.

Comment: so I have to remove ' from 

imagePath = "@"+"'" + imagePath +"'"  ;

finally  : 
imagePath = "@"+ imagePath  ;

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't bother with the second line in your question. The path in this answer should be enough for you to connect. (Assuming permissions, existance, etc..)

Comment: @MSTdev I'd suggest using [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dd781134(v=vs.100).aspx) instead of concatenating strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do anything without the permission of the application provider, Because they hide the URL of the folder location with some IP or their customized URL.